# I want these two graphs to agree in color setting. One is a density map of the other 3d graph

Tags: plotting, color

I want these two graphs to agree in color setting.
The 3d map and the code are:

```
Plot3D[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, MeshStyle -> White, 
 PlotRange -> {-5, 15}, PlotTheme -> BlackBackground, Axes -> none]
```

[image]
The density map and code are:

```
DensityPlot[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotPoints -> 35, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {Range[-10, 10, 10], Range[-0.8, 0.8, 0.4]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

How can I make the first one agree in colors with the second one?, where blue zones indicate low altitude and orange zones indicate high altitude.

Comment: Use the same `ColorFunction` for both.

Comment: I previously advised you to include code for your plots. Now, where is the code for this one?

Answer (score 3):

```
DensityPlot[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
PlotPoints -> 35, 
MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, 
Mesh -> {Range[-10, 10, 10], 
Range[-0.8, 0.8, 0.4]}, 
MeshStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, 
Axes -> True, 
AxesLabel -> Automatic]
    
Plot3D[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7},
MeshStyle -> White,
PlotRange -> {-5, 15},
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
Axes -> None]
```

[image]

See `ColorFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

DensityPlot[2 x^2 - 2 y^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
 PlotPoints -> 35,
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &},
 Mesh -> {Range[-10, 10, 10],
   Range[-0.8, 0.8, 0.4]},
 MeshStyle -> {Black, Dashed},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The function range reflected by the [`BarLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) is

```
{min, max} = #[{2 x^2 - 2 y^2, -4 <= x <= 4, -3 <= y <= 3}, 
    {x, y}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}

(* {-18, 32} *)
```

However, since the [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) of the [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) is restricted to `{-5, 15}` the  color range is not aligned with that of the [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html). This can be seen by overlaying the `Plot3D` on the full `Plot3D` (which corresponds to the `DensityPlot`).

```
Show[
 Plot3D[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
  MeshStyle -> White,
  PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
  Axes -> None,
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 Plot3D[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, 
  MeshStyle -> White,
  PlotRange -> {-5, 15},
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
  Axes -> None,
  ClippingStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

To align the color ranges, rescale

```
Plot3D[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, MeshStyle -> White,
 PlotRange -> {-5, 15},
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, {min, max}]] &),
 Axes -> True,
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {min, max}}]]
```

[image]

Verifying that the colors are aligned,

```
Show[
 Plot3D[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, MeshStyle -> White,
  PlotRange -> All,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
  Axes -> None,
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 Plot3D[x^2/0.5 - y^2/0.5, {x, -7, 7}, {y, -7, 7}, MeshStyle -> White,
  PlotRange -> {-5, 15},
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Rescale[#, {min, max}]] &),
  Axes -> True,
  ClippingStyle -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 from me. Much more comprehensive than my quickly dashed-off answer (after which I noted you had suggested in a comment). Mine provided an answer. Yours provides explanation and understanding.